# Are capitalism and communism equivalent in attributable mass murders?

Tags: communism, statistics, capitalism

When the topic of communism comes up in the US, most automatically dismiss it due to the tens or hundreds of millions who died at the hands of communist regimes.

As a counterpoint, some say that the amount of mass murder caused by capitalism is comparable.  Thus, if mass deaths are used to dismiss communism, then capitalism also should be discredited.

Is the counterpoint premise valid, that capitalism has caused an equivalent amount of mass death as communism?

UPDATE: Since I cannot answer my own question, here is the relevant wiki article.  The question has been investigated and communist regimes apparently have killed many more people than any other sort of regime.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_killings_under_Communist_regimes#Comparison_to_other_mass_killings

> Daniel Goldhagen argues that 20th century Communist regimes "have
>   killed more people than any other regime type." Other scholars in the
>   fields of Communist studies and genocide studies, such as Steven
>   Rosefielde, Benjamin Valentino, and R.J. Rummel, have come to similar
>   conclusions. Rosefielde states that it is possible the "Red Holocaust"
>   killed more non-combatants than "Ha Shoah" and "Japan's Asian
>   holocaust" combined, and "was at least as heinous, given the
>   singularity of Hitler's genocide." Rosefielde also notes that "while
>   it is fashionable to mitigate the Red Holocaust by observing that
>   capitalism killed millions of colonials in the twentieth century,
>   primarily through man-made famines, no inventory of such felonious
>   negligent homicides comes close to the Red Holocaust total."

Comment: You might have to be slightly careful in defining your terms here, since it's relatively rare for a regime to explicitly define itself as capitalist, whereas "communist" is more common label for left-authorian movements.

Comment: You'll have to provide some sources for your second sentence. Also you should clarify whether you're comparing events of mass death or just total deaths that result from the systems existence. If you're talking about events of mass death you're going to find it hard to top China's Great Leap Forward or the USSR's Holodomor

Comment: I downvoted this question because I don't think that such body count comparisons serve any purpose. First, how to count the victims of each ideology would be very subjective, because of the many people who die or have a reduced live expectancy due to secondary and tertiary effects of ideology-based decisions. And what about casualties which are results of decisions which are not actually influenced by ideology? Second, even if it were possible to calculate a bodycount, it would be meaningless to compare them directly because these ideologies were imposed on different numbers of people.

Comment: Now "hundreds of millions" is exaggerated even by the standards of anticommunism.

Comment: Capitalism and communism are economic models.  Dictators can operate in either model and perform mass killings.  No communist state has ever existed, so by one interpretation, the number of deaths caused by communism is 0.

Comment: Its truly impossible to categorize these things.  Is operation Linebacker II (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Linebacker_II)  Capitalism deaths, Fight for Democracy deaths, imperialist deaths, or...other?  Are deaths prior to communist Utopia considered deaths from communism, or are they deaths from dictators with failed communist implements? You can validly argue either side.   Interesting musing, horrible question

Comment: Bodycounts used to justify political action, (or inaction), are ubiquitous in political rhetoric, so this question seems germane.  The fact that the bodycount numbers themselves are often cooked is no reason to abandon numeration itself.  Rather we should contrast various estimates, and the methods used to derive their estimates, while considering what those estimates mean to their authors.

Comment: In the title you say "mass murder" and in the text you say "mass death". Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Tried to research a feasible answer to this, found an article at global research https://www.globalresearch.ca/capitalism-and-slavery/5506347 that would suggest any death related to slavery would be included in this number (Marx would as well, he noted slavery fueled capitalism).  Don't really agree with it, but the argument is there.

Comment: @immibis, We shouldn't conflate the terms *death* and *murder*, but it's  relevant that political bodycount estimators sometimes *do* conflate those terms, sometimes quite flexibly -- *i.e.* counting *murders* only for one group, and *deaths* for the other.  Naturally the *deaths* count is usually greater,  "proving" that those associated with that number are the greater evil.

Comment: @agc And that is more-or-less what I called out the asker on attempting to do. Someone who answered by reading the question body would say "Capitalism caused XXX deaths" and because of the title it could easily be interpreted as "Capitalism murdered XXX people". Or communism, depending on the reader's political views. Or the answer could state for example "Capitalism murdered XXX people and communism caused XXX deaths".

Comment: To add to a lot of pertinent comments here this is a question more suitable to History.SE where you can go for parts (death toll in from a specific goverment) and debate who is the culprint for Korea or Vietnam war (where both sides excelled in atrocites) and for Economics.SE to debate negative impacts from economics politics

Comment: To answer my own question, apparently the issue has been investigated and communist regimes clearly have killed many more than any other regime.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_killings_under_Communist_regimes#Comparison_to_other_mass_killings

Comment: @immibis I have fixed the question to only say "murder".  Can you unflag the question?

Comment: @JamesK I found a historian (previous Harvard prof) who answered my very question, so it is not opinion based.  Can you unflag the question?

Comment: @user4012 I found a historian (previous Harvard prof) who answered my very question, so it is not opinion based.  Can you unflag the question?

Comment: @bytebuster I found a historian (previous Harvard prof) who answered my very question, so it is not opinion based.  Can you unflag the question?

Comment: @Alexei I found a historian (previous Harvard prof) who answered my very question, so it is not opinion based.  Can you unflag the question?

Comment: @Communisty I found a historian (previous Harvard prof) who answered my very question, so it is not opinion based.  Can you unflag the question?

Answer (score 3):

It just so happens that at least three of the worst acts of genocide, Stalin's purges, the killing fields of Cambodia, and the cultural revolution in China, happened under the auspices of an ostensibly communist government.

However, there is nothing about either the communist or capitalist movements that encourages mass murder.

In actual practice, communist governments tend to be guided by a political elite, with the leaders chosen by a privileged few, while capitalist governments tend to be more democratic. So that prevalence of mass murderers may be more a result of the absence of direct accountability of the leaders (as in no direct elections) to the people, than anything.

You tend to behave better when you can be voted out of office.

Comment: Are you identifying capitalism with unlimited democracy?

Comment: No, simply noting that capitalist countries tend to have a more representational form of government, while communist counties put 'the party' in charge of everything. True that a citizen can join the party, but at least in practice, there isn't a mechanism for dissent or disagreement available to the average citizen in a communist government.

Comment: But historically some of the more egregious capitalist actors have been non-national, e.g. the Dutch and the British East India Companies.

Comment: How about the genocide in the Americas after it's 'discovery' by Columbus? Does that not count?

Answer (score 1):

This is at least as much a commentary rather than it is an answer, concerning what it would take to meaningfully count deaths attributable to a given grouping or category, such as capitalism vs. communism, monarchy vs. republic, religion vs. secularism, *etc.*

Certain variable details seem to be taken for granted in most such accountings and are often left undefined:

1. How many people have *lived* where they would have died, (in a sense, were saved from death), due to a category's merits?  Suppose grouping *X*'s bodycount is ***i***, but its lives saved is ***j***, and ***j > i***.
2. If we let ***k = j - i***, what would ***k*** be if *neither* grouping existed?  Unless the groupings are each both all-encompassing and mutually exclusive, it seems like there would need to be at least a third agreed upon grouping whose numbers formed a fixed basis of comparison.
3. An agreed upon human "*life*" to count.  Definitions vary according to the size of the window that constitutes life, (when it starts and stops), its quality or relative value as measured by those in power, (*i.e.* slaves regarded as half-people, uncharismatic mutations, the sick and aged, outsiders, outlaws, enemies, militarily weaker populations with confiscatable possessions, those with "*fates worse than death*", *et al*), and *whose* lives, (responsibility for *all* of a wars' deaths might be attributed to the defeated).  Equally valid metrics might be measured in people-years, (add up the ages), or total national body mass over time, (add up everyone's weight), or brain mass, (just suppose), or souls sent to heaven, (for highly-informed theocracies).
4. Causes of death.  Bullet and bomb deaths seem to be common metrics.   Prisons, labor and internment camp deaths sometimes are counted, especially when these are uncommonly deadly.  Man-made disaster deaths indirectly caused by a grouping's errors may be a common future metric.  National diets, pastimes, industries, accounting practices, pets, and hygiene.

Any of these details, however odd, if clearly specified and enumerated might make for interesting (maybe even useful) numbers and comparisons.  Granted some or many combinations of such data would be by default complete nonsense, but the labor alone involved in compiling such data tells a lot about the beliefs and hopes of those who commissioned that labor and those who invoke such numbers.  The same way that the Egyptian Pyramids may not be *useful* in the way its designers had hoped, but that are still useful to us today for reasons those designers might not have foreseen.